# Get multiple strings from json controller result ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a button sending an input from a text field in a form to my mvc controller using ajax. I now want the controller to return 2 strings as a json, and fill those strings into html inputs.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getName(string Name)
    {

        string SecondString = "secondString";

        return Json(Name, SecondString);
    }
```

**View**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", 
                url: "home/getName", 
                data: { 
                    Name: $("#txtName").val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#FirstTextFieldToFill').val(result);
                    $('#SecondTextFieldToFill').val(result);

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're wrongly assigned parameters to the [`Json()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method to return response of `JsonResult`, because the second parameter is `JsonRequestBehavior` or `contentType`. You should return `Controller.Json()` response with [single parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_Json_System_Object_) like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetName(string Name)
{
    string SecondString = "secondString";

    return Json(new { Name = Name, SecondString = SecondString });
}
```

And then modify your AJAX call to return 2 strings from response by using property names:

```
$("#btnGet").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "@Url.Action("GetName", "Home"), 
        data: { Name: $("#txtName").val() },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#FirstTextFieldToFill').val(result.Name);
            $('#SecondTextFieldToFill').val(result.SecondString);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked like this:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getName(string Name)
    {

        string SecondString = "secondString";

        return Json(new { Name, SecondString });
    }
```

**View**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", 
                url: "home/getName", 
                data: { 
                    Name: $("#txtName").val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#FirstTextFieldToFill').val(result.Name);
                    $('#SecondTextFieldToFill').val(result.SecondString);
                    $('#SecondTextFieldToFill').show();
                    $('#FirstTextFieldToFill').show();


                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you should create a class having two string eg.

```
public class example
{
    public string FirstString {get; set;}
    public string SecondString {get; set;}
}
```

create object of the class in the controller and add the strings to it serialize to json and return

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getName(string Name)
    {
        example eg=new example();
        eg.FirstString ="your first string";
        eg.SecondString ="your second string";
        string jsonString= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eg);
        return Json(jsonString);
    }
```

JS file should extract the strings from the json object

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", 
                url: "home/getName", 
                data: { 
                    Name: $("#txtName").val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    var jsonResult=JSON.parse( result );
                    $('#FirstTextFieldToFill').val(jsonResult.FirstString);
                    $('#SecondTextFieldToFill').val(jsonResult.SecondString);

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

    });
});
```

Dependency required in controller are
`JsonConvert` is from the namespace `Newtonsoft.Json`

Use NuGet to download the package

"Project" -> "Manage NuGet packages" -> "Search for "newtonsoft json". -> click "install"

Comment: Thanks man. Already worked with the solution posted before. This one worked as well